# Is it possible to have a plain java library module depending on android SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my multi-module Android Studio project, I would like to create a plain java module. But in that module, I also want to be able to use certain Android API. Is this possible? If yes, how should build.gradle look like?

Thanks
jia

Comment: What is the value in creating a "plain java module", over a library project, in this case? After all, you cannot use that Java module in anything other than an Android app.

Comment: This is not meant for standard phone app, but for custom hardware. We want to be able to share the same jar among multiple applications on the device.

Answer (score 8):

As long as the Android functionality that you need is in a jar instead of an aar, then you should be able to do this fairly easily as my team has a couple of artifacts like this. For Android jar artifacts in Maven Central, you just need to add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
```

If the functionality is in one of the artifacts installed via the Android SDK Manager, then you can just add the dependency as above, but you'll need to add the local Android repo to pull the artifacts:

```
maven { url "file:///${System.env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository" }
```

**Edit**

Also forgot to mention, you'll want to mark the Android artifacts as provided so that you don't get dependency clashes. You can do that by using the following:

```
configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}
dependencies {
    provided('com.google.android:android:4.1.1.2')
}
```

Let me know if you need an example build.gradle and I will add one.

**Edit 2**

Below is an example build.gradle that we use for one of our projects.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'jxr'

group = 'com.example'
archivesBaseName = 'project-name'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

configurations {
    provided
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/' }
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath('net.davidecavestro:gradle-jxr-plugin:0.1')
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    if (project.hasProperty("mavenLocal")) {
        maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository" }
    }
    maven { url "file:///${System.env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.2')
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4')
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:15.0')
    provided('com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2')
    testCompile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11')
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.8')
}

test {
    dependsOn ':assemble'
    testLogging {
        showExceptions = true
        showStackTraces = true
        exceptionFormat = "full"
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = test.classpath
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverate reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
    }
}

pmd.ignoreFailures = true
pmdTest.enabled = false
pmdMain.enabled = true
pmdMain {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

findbugs.ignoreFailures = true
findbugs.excludeFilter = file('./findbugs-exclude-filter.xml')
findbugsTest.enabled = false
findbugsMain.enabled = true
findbugsMain {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
    distributionUrl = "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${gradleVersion}-all.zip"
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from "${projectDir}/build/docs"
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

uploadSite.dependsOn(':check')
check.dependsOn('sourcesJar')
check.dependsOn('javadoc')
check.dependsOn('jacocoTestReport')
check.dependsOn('projectReport')
check.dependsOn('jxr')
```

Comment: Bradford2000, a sample build.gradle would be much appreciated. I'm quite new to android and java build tools.

Comment: In my case, we are using android 4.2.2 which isn't in maven central. And SDK manager doesn't seem have put it in local m2repository directory either.

Comment: I don't think the versions of com.google.android:android match up to the android OS versions. The latest version that is available in either Maven Central or jCenter is 4.1.1.4.

Comment: Is there a way to check which version of com.google.android:android you have locally?

Comment: com.google.android:android is actually a Maven dependency hosted in Maven Central. You can see all of the released version here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/android.